# JQuery scrollable circular: true doesn't work with size: 2 with autoscroll (only works with size: 1)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-tools

JQuery Tools autoscroll - circular: true doesn't work if size: 2. Only works if size: 1.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    window.api = $(".scrollable")
    .scrollable({size: 2, circular: true})
    .navigator({idPrefix: 'a', history: true})
    .autoscroll({autoplay: true, interval: 3000})
    .data("scrollable"); 


    api.onBeforeSeek(function() {

    // return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Please help